# Software Library Vulnerability Tracking

Tags: web-application, known-vulnerabilities

I'm looking to improve the security posture of a web app specifically with respect to OWASP A9 - Using Components with Known Vulnerabilities.

Is anyone aware of any comprehensive data sources aside from the NVD/CVE DB that I might use instead of relying on each library's vendor/author? The NVD is far from comprehensive, and manually searching each site is tedious, so I'm hoping to find some better ***method*** (not product or service) to approach this.

Comment: Black Duck has the Open Hub: https://www.openhub.net/explore/projects

Comment: This question likely won't go anywere as it's a bit of a product recommendation (which the mods in their wisdom have decided is off-topic) with that said you could also look at source clear (https://srcclr.com/) as I believe their product covers this kind of area

Comment: I was concerned that people might interpret it that way, but I'm trying to carefully focus on information sources, not products that ingest them.

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar a while back to ensure we were keeping up with security updates. It's all manual, though: I can't help you automate it but I can tell you how long it took me and give an example of what I ended up using.

The initial setup took a couple days (we use > 75 libraries), and since then it's just been an hour or less per week to maintain it (not counting the time to actually update the libraries we use). I ended up with a matrix in a spreadsheet, with a row for each library we used. Then the columns were:

- version we use
- last version I checked
- NEWS file (any issues I identified from scanning the NEWS or other readme files provided by the library)
- CVEs (known to exist in our version)
- latest version available from our vendor (we don't pull directly from upstream)
- status, which says "OK" if NEWS and CVEs are empty and latest-version-checked matches latest-version-available, or I manually set it to some other status like "needs future fix" or whatever is appropriate
- notes

I filled out the table with our libraries and their versions, then downloaded the full [CVE database](https://cve.mitre.org/data/downloads/index.html) in text format and used a good text editor to search it for each of our applications. If there were any CVEs for our libraries I listed them in the CVE column and added notes about the version where they were fixed and/or why they applied to us (or in the case of some well-known CVEs, why they *didn't*).

I also skimmed the NEWS files for most of the libraries that had newer versions available than what we were using, though I gave up on that after a while when it didn't yield anything useful that wasn't already captured in a CVE.

Then I subscribed to an RSS feed of [newly-categorized CVEs](https://nvd.nist.gov/download/nvd-rss-analyzed.xml). It's fairly low-volume, though bursty, so when new CVEs come in I quickly scan them for issues and update my spreadsheet if there's anything that applies to us.

I also made a cron job to scan a [different list of newly-filed CVEs](https://cassandra.cerias.purdue.edu/CVE_changes/), but that didn't seem to add any value beyond what the NVD RSS feed provided.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is more or less what I'm currently doing. However, there are a couple of problems I've identified with this approach. More than anything else, lots of vendors/authors never get CVE IDs for their security flaws, for example this one from angular.js: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/13453


I can't even find a mention of angular in the NVD, but there is an entry in the (new to me) srcclr: https://srcclr.com/security/arbitrary-code-execution-through-svg/javascript/s-2253

Comment: seen cve-search/cve-search ?

Comment: cve-search looks like it might be a useful tool to automate CVE searches, but it's still shy of a comprehensive approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Security Tracker has a search capability to comb multiple sources for reported vulnerabilities:

http://securitytracker.com/search/search.html

Good luck!

edit: sorry, ST doesn't search eternal sites, everything is internal to ST itself. I personally use it as one information source (free version). Not sure why I'm getting down voted.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because the OP specifically asked for a _method_ or _process_, **not** a product, service, or website. It would also help if you added some info about where ST gets its info from. Is it just a re-hash of the CVE db, or does it pull in something else?

Comment: Do you have a method for consuming data from ST that's non-manual?